# java - TreeMap lower/higher getters

Tags: java, reverse, treemap

Maybe my logic stopped working for a bit, but I find this behavior confusing. Suppose I have a TreeMap as follows:

```
  TreeMap<Integer, Double> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    map.put(123, 0.5);
    map.put(678, 1.0);
    map.put(567, 0.1);

    int key = 100;
```

Now, I want to use the `map.lowerEntry(key)` and according to the documentation of the getter:

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key strictly less than the given key, or null if there is no such key.

I would expect `null` as a result, but the system call `System.out.println("Lower than "+key+ " is "+map.lowerEntry(key));` produces `Lower than 100 is 123=0.5`. If I use `map.higherEntry(key)` which is documented as

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the least key strictly greater than the given key, or null if there is no such key.

then I get the desired result, but it is counter-intuitive based on the documentation. I guess calling the `Collections.reverseOrder()` comparator on the TreeMap inverts the logic applied inside the map?

**EDIT**
Using a TreeSet I get consistent behavior (regarding the function names) when it is initialized with the `Collections.reverseOrder()` comparator:

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    set.add(123);
    set.add(678);
    set.add(567);

int key = 200;
System.out.println("Lower than "+key+ " is "+set.tailSet(key));
```

produces `Lower than 200 is [123]` which I would expect.
Is this inconsistency between TreeMap and TreeSet normal? Can someone please explain please? Thank you.

Comment: Of course `Collections.reverseOrder()` will reverse the definition of lower/higher - just as the name says.

Comment: Well I guess that should be specified in the documentation or a flag should be put in place in case the order is reversed to keep the consistency

Comment: Well keep in mind that `reverseOrder()` is just a special implementation of `Comparator` that will reverse the natural order of the keys (as defined by their implementation of `compareTo()`). There might be a multitude of different comparators or comparable implementations for a multitude of situations and you can't handle all those cases in the tree implementation or even documentation. In fact the tree map doesn't even know the comparator you passed reverses the order.

Comment: I am aware of the multitude of comparators and so on, but then why the implementation of the `TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder())` is still able to be consistent while using `set.tailSet(key)` and `set.headSet(key)` even though underlying there is still a TreeMap with the `Collections` comparator?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "still able to be consistent" here but `TreeSet` works the same way as `TreeMap`. `headSet()` will return the "lower" values and `tailSet()` the "higher" values based on the comparator.

Comment: Nope. That is the thing. Try the example I've put in the edit. If I use `tailSet()` I get the values that are lower than my specified `key`, even though the set is initialized with `Collections.reversedOrder()`

Comment: As I said, `tailSet()` returns the "higher" values as defined by the comparator. Thus it is similar to `higherEntry()` (you iterate from lower to higher or from head to tail). The error lies in using `tailSet()` instead of `headSet()` here.

Comment: You state that you get the desired result using higherEntry, which is what? Null?

Comment: @momo yeah, as stated I would expect `null`

Comment: @Thomas and isn't it logical if you say `headSet` to return you the subset of values "higher than" a certain value... being a HEAD set and tailSet to return you the "lower than" values ? being the TAIL of the set? I have to have the order of the elements reversed in the TreeSet so that the actual names of those getters are consistent with the results they produce. In any case, thank you for your time

Comment: Well head = front, tail = back. If you iterate over an ordered list you normally start at the front where the lower values are defined (i.e. ascending iteration is default in most situations) so head->tail = lower->higher. As stated multiple times: it all depends on the definition of "lower", which in case of a reverse comparator is reversed from the default.

Comment: @Thomas Hehehe.. we understand each other, there is no issue there, but I find the documentation and/or names of the functions misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and "summarize" the comments above for some structure:

`TreeMap.lowerEntry(key)` and `TreeSet.headSet(key)` have basically the same behavior which is they return the elements which are lower than the key. The same holds for `TreeMap.higherEntry(key)` and `TreeSet.tailSet(key)`.

Using a reverse comparator on either of them would cause the order to be reversed, i.e. higher becomes lower and lower becomes higher. This might seem counterintuitive when the keys/elements are numbers etc. but so would be reversing their sort order.

If you add some semantics to the elements it might be easier to understand:

Let's say we're dealing with a ticketing system that counts the occurence of errors while some person defines priorities for the errors to be fixed.

Now you want to iterate through that list of errors and display them, so you sort them using a `TreeMap<Integer, ErrorDescription>`.

Depending on the semantics of the key you'd use a different comparator:

- If the key is priority, where common conception is lower numbers mean higher priority, you'd just order the map from smallest to highest number, i.e. you just use the standard order.
- If the key is number of occurences you'd most probably want to have the errors with the highest occurences be at the head of the list and thus you'd use a reverse order. However, since integers are defined to be ordered small to high you'd to employ a reversing comparator.

Last, a quote from your last comment:

> I find the documentation and/or names of the functions misleading.

If you consider the example above just adding semantics to numbers would change the meaning of "lower" and "higher". Additionally take into account that numeric keys are just one type of keys, you could also use dates, strings, enums or a multitude of other objects which have a natural order (thus implementing `Comparable`) or need to be ordered on a case-by-case basis (thus using a `Comparator`).

Because there are so many different situations the documentation has to apply to it's hard to write it in a way that fits everything. The meaning of "lower" and "higher" depends on the situation anyway and thus it's easiest to just use that wording and leave the interpretation of the semantics to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the answer you want is here: [`TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) constructor

> Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator ...
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `comparator` - the comparator that will be used to order this map. If null, the natural ordering of the keys will be used.

Then, you should read *less than* and *greater than* only with respect to this `comparator`.

Also, as Thomas has pointed out, you're probably confusing with the meaning of `tailSet(key)`. From the doc, it should give you elements that are *greater than or equal to* the key. So, in the the reverse order, you get lower values.

Comment: Hi dejvuth. Thanks for your time. Can you please logically explain me what is for you a tailSet and what is a headSet, regardless of the java documentation

Comment: `tailSet` and `headSet` give you a `SortedSet`, which order you elements from head to tail. In natural ordering, it's in ascending order.